# Simple list creation

Tags: python

I'm new on python and I have a problem

I have a word and i want in return a list like that: 
outlist = ["word1, word2, word3, ecc....]
this is what I tried:

```
numberlist=list(range(1,1000))
numberlist=(','.join("'{0}'".format(x) for x in numberlist))

list=["word" + number for number in numberlist]
for elem in sq:
       print (elem)
```

I have a list in return but its wrong, I cant find a way to obtain what I want.
Where is the error? 
thanks for the help

Comment: Change line 2 to `numberlist = map(str, numberlist)`.

Comment: Where does that `sq` variable come from?

Comment: Not a good idea to call your list `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `join` is wrong. The simplest solution would be:

```
print ["word" + str(i) for i in range(1, 1000)]
```

This gives:

```
In [4]: ["word" + str(k) for k in range(5)]
Out[4]: ['word0', 'word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']
```

`join` is used to return a string that represents the concatenation of multiple strings in an iterable, so in this case you could use it to return a string, joined by comma:

```
In [5]: ','.join(["word" + str(k) for k in range(5)])
Out[5]: 'word0,word1,word2,word3,word4'
```

Comment: Oh my, thanks! Python is so beautiful! One line and everything is done!

Comment: haha, yeah :) don't forget to accept the answer, if it helped :D